# UIScrollView Zoom in/out and find the zoomed view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

My problem goes like this...
I have a ViewController class and i create a UIScrollView and add it as subview of my viewcontroller's view, basically i set the following things .

```
_randomView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
_randomView.minimumZoomScale=1;
_randomView.maximumZoomScale=5;
_randomView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubView:_randomView];
```

Now from some other place in my class based on callback i add some other views(eg. someOtherView) to my _randomView which i zoom in/out using

```
- (nullable UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
 return someOtherView
}
```

Now since my application is tab based application if the user goes from current screen to some other screen i show a small window wherein i show the view of my ViewController class. Everything works fine when user zooms in/out, the problem is in default state i.e zoom scale 1  and i go to some other tab and i add my ViewController's view to my small window's view it works fine but if i zoom in my view and then i switch to other tab the view shows BLACK(default background color of Viewcontroller's view)....

After further debugging i see that when i zoom in and i see BLACK view when i switch to some other screen the scroll bars position in UIScrollView(view zoomed) is different, if i again scroll those to top and left and switch back i can see the view back again.

Is there a way i can get rid of this issue, i want to be able to show the zoomed view in my other tab's window as well??

Someone please help and yes i am using autolayout.

Comment: I believe this issue will need multiple steps to fix. First one is providing enough code to reproduce/understand your issue or even better; try creating a fresh project that has minimum code that still produces this issue. Then upload this code or project.

Comment: @MaticOblak - Is there a way atleast via which i can get the zoomed/scaled view, say suppose when i zoomed in can i somehow retrieve the zoomed view ??

Comment: Don’t you already have a method viewForZoomingInScrollView which does exactly that by definition?

Comment: actually it's the view that will be scaled/zoomed... but then what about the view that has come out after scaling ?I have this and i return the view that needs scaling.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. It would truly be helpful if added some more code or more detail explanation on what you are doing..

Comment: viewForZoomingInScrollView  - Asks the delegate for the view to scale when zooming is about to occur in the scroll view. (as per apple) so i return my view which needs scaling from here. But my problem is after scaling has been completed can i somehow retrieve that new scaled view